# How can I group objects alphabetacally within an array by a specific key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects of countries with some values for every country. But I need to put them in a list, alphabetically.

```js
// globalBrands
{
    [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Argentina',
            content: [{url: 'www.argentinca.com', title: "Argentina Title"}]z
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Canada',
            content: [{url: 'www.canada.com', title: "Canada Title"}]
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            title: 'Chile',
            content: [{url: 'www.chile.com', title: "Chile Title"}]
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            title: 'China',
            content: [{url: 'www.china.com', title: "China Title"}]
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            title: 'Finland',
            content: [{url: 'www.finland.com', title: "Finland Title"}]
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            title: 'France',
            content: [{url: 'www.france.com', title: "France Title"}]
        },
    ]
}
```

I created a new array where the output was supposed to be something like this or something similiar which gives me access to the properties of the countries sorted alphabetically

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        letter: 'A',
        country: ['Argentina'],
        content: [{url: 'www.some.com', title: "A Title"}]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        letter: 'C',
        country: ['Canada', 'Chile', 'China'],
        content: [{url: 'www.canada.com', title: "Canada Title"}, {url: 'www.chile.com', title: "Chile Title"}, {url: 'www.china.com', title: "China Title"}]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        letter: 'F',
        country: ['Finland', 'France'],
        content: [{url: 'www.finland.com', title: "Finlanda Title"}, {url: 'www.france.com', title: "France Title"}]
    },
]
```

I have this 2 functions:

```
function mergeObjectsInUnique<T> (array: T[], property: unknown): T[] {
    const newArray = new Map();

    array.forEach((item: T) => {
      // @ts-ignore
      const propertyValue = item[property];

      if (newArray.has(propertyValue)) {
        return newArray.set(propertyValue, { ...item, ...newArray.get(propertyValue) });
      }

      return newArray.set(propertyValue, item);
    });

    return Array.from(newArray.values());
}

const sortBrands = (): NewBrandInterface[] => {
    let newArr: NewBrandInterface[] = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < globalBrands.length; i++) {
      const itemIdx = globalBrands[i];

      // This structure can be change to whatever is better
      newArr = [
        ...newArr,
        ...[{
          id: itemIdx.drupal_id,
          letter: itemIdx.title.charAt(0),
          country: [itemIdx.title],
          content: itemIdx.content.map(g => ({
            url: g.url,
            title: g.title
          }))
        }]
      ];
    }

    return mergeObjectsInUnique(newArr, 'letter');
};
```

That code what it does is to just return one item in the country array. Like for the letter `C` there are 3 titles/countries that start with the letter `C`, Canada, Chile and China, so all of them should be returned within the `country` array and its proper values (url, title). The same for example for Finland and France.

What am I doing wrong?

If you see the output on the playground, it kinda deletes the items and just leaves one with the starting letter. For the `C` it only leaves there Canada but it removes the other 2.

I created an example with the exact same code I posted, [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDKgNYEEQBMAqwYANhAJLjTxLIDeAUMsgK5TED8AXMgM5hSgA5gG5GyMEVLc+AkCPoBfevVCRYiFADkIAdwBCUOHgprqKBk2C5uIZgFsARtFFNSYNdP5CXyBAHtmcCgAT09ZQQBtAF0ff0pwbnQQbDxCEnJKdSRo0SV6OL5kQWI-BzhiAyNcHmQAXmQIsSYLJlbLa2QARgAaJrbxSQhuAHIsKEEIcFA4Yd7+1rjIBIbaFjYRnU2AOjhxyYkQBDgt-ztZgfTuACIxiamQOGQ00ivkBSi+hTnWlvmrbgATN95hJLshhgBhIxwXAzYH9Rb7bgRVasYgbbZHB6wk5+M7dC5SZBXKHYx7PCCvd6feG-fr-ZAAZnhbVBRMhAAtgKRZn02ojlii1ujwZsdCcuaRcfjCUNiRDJSgKVSPm0vn06W0GQAWFmtNlyznTXnzJgCsDI1HrUWYrkPaXnA3XBXTJ6DFU0jV81oMgCseqYTvBADFQMQqibTebLcKMeKYGGqg6CUGrqGQOG8G70h61bTve1uP6C7KRsHDIcIJH5tGVrGbfGK0hk6XieWjDRlW9Va11R96DBAggJH4QMg7NAJgB5BwAKwgw54FAAqiBgABHZgQAA8+AAfMgABS7QyhJ7RAkABygfkv0DAZ8CGBAfh0IAAlNx8NE6H0CmBkBAXQxlPOpAN0ZAAFk4EvQ931EPoTzgYIthgPwoAAUUQDlD0PIgIDsL93zqA9NWQAB6cjkAAATAHgAFpgEEF8oAgb1-2Qa9b3vYIADVyi3MD8LsCIuLvKAHxiZQ-hgI8gJ0EDkK2Dk4B4Q8xJ4-jiC3d9iLIphWLAVgx3kxSUJ4CAwHUm9xIfLStwJVYtmc4SCWcrZTKgU8tgmKyNIkviBIgYiFHg708nmQzjPAhSvKUiy-JszSgoJYSwrVMK+iiqAxzM1CbzsQ9PO8gA3IK1N03JlA4nh0LASo8Bqeo4O4bR9ArXATCoDQf1qUi+jcGKQNa3QGs6zIzF6hopL6NCoCPQbgDAgAGYRkCW7cihKMoKg6ngtlIOQwA5NbgAAajOvT2NHQphLIXAAA8wOKUpyjGngImAGb5mKsDGlNZB3OKgNAeclES0LdbIDse6Hq2KwQdcSyPChgjYa2A0JV2LArOW99Ed8AIgjPT7ofRg0ogJ2s7se3F4jALY7Bgw9BBIo99P6NFuEELY0QJwNBm5jHBght5dJLal5iktVpNabKxwnPYZ3nRcVzXTcICK4CvIJYY3DUYYwoUBCCj8KUSkEQ9VmK6Q6veuCxeEIA).

Comment: Perhaps I missed something, but to sort the first data structure in your question alphabetically on the country name is as simple as this: `globalBrands.sort((a, b) => a.title - b.title)`

Comment: @RandyCasburn I need to group them by letter. If you see the first json I posted, there is no `letter`, then I create an an array `newArr` with an object containing a key/alue `letter: itemIdx.title.charAt(0)`. There I get the first letter of every country. If there are 10 countries with the same letter, I have to group them.

Comment: So is the object with `id: 3, letter: C, ['Finland', 'France']` a typo?

Comment: Yikes. Good catch, it is a typo, @RandyCasburn. And there on that example I placed the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing, but if you are looking to refactor your input array grouped by letter you can use a single [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) call.

```js
const input = [{ id: 1, title: 'Argentina', content: [{ url: 'www.argentinca.com', title: "Argentina Title" }] }, { id: 2, title: 'Canada', content: [{ url: 'www.canada.com', title: "Canada Title" }] }, { id: 3, title: 'Chile', content: [{ url: 'www.chile.com', title: "Chile Title" }] }, { id: 4, title: 'China', content: [{ url: 'www.china.com', title: "China Title" }] }, { id: 5, title: 'Finland', content: [{ url: 'www.finland.com', title: "Finland Title" }] }, { id: 5, title: 'France', content: [{ url: 'www.france.com', title: "France Title" }] },];

let i = 1;
const result = Object.values(
  input.reduce((acc, { id, title, content }) => {
    const letter = title[0]

    acc[letter] = acc[letter] || { id: i++, letter, country: [], content: [] }
    // or using logical nullish assignment
    // acc[letter] ??= { id: i++, letter, country: [], content: [] }

    acc[letter].country.push(title);
    acc[letter].content.push(...content);

    return acc
  }, {})) // initialize accumulator as an empty object

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Can I know what is this for `??=`? it throws an error: `Parsing error: Expression expected.eslint`

Comment: It's the [logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) operator, for compatibility you may have to use an `||` shortcircuit instead, I'll add it to the snippet.

Comment: Nice answer! My suggestion would be to use better variable names. `reduce()` in general is hard to understand, so having `a` and `k`, makes the code even more complex :)

(BTW, I like the comment with the "nullish assignment" option )

Comment: Thats a fair point, I'll edit it to clarify the variable roles.